# Promotheus - query to get increase percentage of events

Tags: prometheus

I have an histogram of requests with path and status codes...How can I alert if the errors are increasing with 20% in the last hour compared with the hour before?

one metric sample:

```
{instance="someIp",instance_hostname="someHost",job="someAppName",le="+Inf",method="GET",path="somePath",status_code="500"}
```

I should rely on rate function? something like:

```
rate(http_request_duration_seconds{job="someProject", status_code="500"}[60m])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the ratio of the error rate over the past hour to the error rate over the previous 1 hour:

```
(
  rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{status_code="500"}[1h])
    /
  rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{status_code="500"}[1h] offset 1h)
)
  >
1.2
```

This will check for an increase in the absolute number of errors. If you want to check for an increase in the relative number of errors (e.g. 10% of requests failed over the past hour vs 5%  over the previous hour), then you'd need to divide the error rate by total request rate before comparing to the same thing 1 hour ago.

Or you may want to combine the two, and alert if the relative number of errors has increased by X%, and the absolute number is over some noise threshold (so that it doesn't trigger if you got 2 requests over the past hour and one of them failed).

Comment: Thanks Alin, it really works. It's a secondary part of an app I made and had no experience with Prometheus but looks you can do plenty of things with it.